# Control the growth rate of dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems

How do I control the growth rate of this dynamical system?

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&a_{n+1} = a_n + ka_n (2000 - a_n)\\
&a_0 = 4
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

I experimented with multiple values of $k$ and i still can't find a way to control the growth.

(For additional context, is there a way such that this converges to a finite number and without this- ever exceeding $2000$?)

Comment: $a_{n+1}$ is increasing with respect to $a_n $ until $2000$  if $k>0$

Comment: is there a way for it to be aₙ < 2000? (by changing k)

Answer (score 3):

$$a_{n+1} = ka_n\left(\left(2000+\frac1 k  \right) -a_n \right)$$
Define $x_n =\frac{k}{2000k+1} \cdot a_n$ then
$$x_{n+1} = (2000k+1)x_n(1-x_n) \tag{1}$$

$(1)$ is the [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map#Behavior_dependent_on_r) and converges to **a** finite value if and only if $(2000k+1) \in [0,3]$, that is
$$-\frac{1}{2000} \le k \le \frac{1}{1000}$$

In this case, the sequence converges to $l \in [0,1)$ such that:
$$l = \cases{0 &if $k \in \left[-\frac1 {2000}, 0  \right]$\\
1-\frac{1}{2000k+1} &if $k \in \left[ 0,\frac{1}{1000}  \right]$\\} 
$$

Comment: why was this converted to xₙ and xₙ₊₁? and also, does this mean that if k falls within that range then the model will never reach 2000? (sorry if obvious questions, i'm barely introductory -level on dynamical systems)

Comment: @Lowell0803 It suffices to replace $a_n = x_n\cdot (2000k+1)/k$ and  $a_{n+1} = x_{n+1}\cdot (2000k+1)/k$ in your initial equation, you will obtain the equation $(1)$. And as you asked in the question the condition of the convergence of the sequence (to 1 single finite number), we need to have $(2000k+1) \in [0,3]$ according to the wiki page.

Comment: @Lowell0803 I added the limit of the sequence in the answer.